# Dask dropna with no arguments

Tags: python, dask, nan

I am running a data pre processing with dask, however when i try to use df.dropna() it returns this error:

TypeError  "You cannot set both the how and thresh arguments at the same time."

even though i have not specified any of the parameters, neither how or thresh.

I have tried specifying how, thresh and subset however the result is always the same.

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducer and full exception/traceback

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I realized that I was using python `3.8`. Using a [supported version](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/develop.html#python-versions) (currently `3.9`, `3.10` or `3.11`) fixed it.